# Incorrect swapping of elements when Algo is correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I have a pretty basic problem here with bubblesort swapping. I am trying to build a sorting visualizer and need to swap the heights of 2 array elements when they are swapped in the bubblesort. I have verified that the algo works along with the animation array holding the correct elements. My problem is that I can't get the correct swapping when I adjust the height for the array bars.
Here is my sandbox :
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-darkness-rpzcr?file=/src/App.js)
EDIT: If you dont want to click on a link heres some code:
BubbleSort.js:

```
const animations = [];

export const swap = (arr, current, next) => {
    animations.push(arr[current]);
    animations.push(arr[next]);
    let curVal = arr[current];
    arr[current] = arr[next];
    arr[next] = curVal;
    
    
    getAnimations(animations);
}

export const getAnimations = (animations) => {
    const newAnims = animations; 
    
    return newAnims; 
}


export const doBubbleSort = (array) => {
         //start the endIndex at the last index of the arrayay
         let newArray = array; 
        
         let endIndex = newArray.length - 1;
         //run the loop until the endIndex(sorted portion) is the 0 (the full newArrayay)
         while(endIndex > 0){
             // count the number of swaps to short circuit the loop if it is already sorted
             let swaps = 0;
             //reset the currentIndex to the beginning of the newArrayay each time a new element is sorted
             let currentIndex = 0;
             // loop over the newArrayay, comparing each pair of elements until the comparison element reaches the sorted portion of the newArrayay
             while(currentIndex < endIndex){
                 // uncomment this line to see the comparison in action
                //console.log(newArray[currentIndex], newArray[currentIndex + 1])
                 // if the current element is greater than the element in front of it
                 if(newArray[currentIndex] > newArray[currentIndex + 1]){
                     //swap the 2 elements using our helper function
                     swap(newArray, currentIndex, currentIndex + 1);
                     // add 1 to the swaps counter
                     swaps++;
                 }
             //increase the currentIndex to continue iterating through the newArrayay
             currentIndex++;
             }
             //stop the loop if there were no swaps because the newArrayay must be already sorted 
             if(swaps === 0)break;
             // subtract the endIndex number to account for the new element added to the newArrayay
             endIndex--;
         }

         return newArray;
}

export default animations;
```

This is the algo. Here is where I try and swap elements to display on sceen :

```
 bubbleSort(){
        let anims = [];
        const sortedArray = doBubbleSort(this.state.array);
        let bars = [];
        
         //Only initial positions
        //console.log(arrayBars); //inital log
        anims = animations;
        //console.log(anims);
        
        for(let i = 0; i < anims.length; i+=2){
            
            let swap = 0;
            let firstBar = anims[i] + 'px';
            let secondBar = anims[i+1] + 'px';
            bars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
            
            console.log('anim: ' + firstBar + ' ' + secondBar);
            
            //console.log(currentArrayBars);
           
            setTimeout(() => {
                let firstIdx = 0; 
                let secondIdx = 0; 

               while(swap == 0)
               {
                   for(let j = 0; j < bars.length; j++){
                       if(bars[j].style.height == firstBar){
                           firstIdx = j; 
                           bars[j].style.backGroundColor = 'red';
                       }
                       else if(bars[j].style.height == secondBar){
                            secondIdx = j; 
                            bars[j].style.backGroundColor = 'red';
                       }
                   }

                   let temp = bars[firstIdx].style.height;
                   bars[firstIdx].style.height = bars[secondIdx].style.height;
                   bars[secondIdx].style.height = temp;


                   swap++;
               }
                
               
               
            
            }, i * 1)
            
            
            
            
        }

        
        
        anims.length = 0;
        
    
    }; 
    
        
render(){
    const {array} = this.state; 
    return (
       <div className = "array-container">
        {array.map((value, idx) => (
                <div className = "array-bar"   key = {idx}
                  style = {{height: `${value}px`}}>
                </div>
        ))}
       
        <button onClick ={() => this.resetArray()}> Generate New Array </button>
        <button onClick ={() => this.bubbleSort()}> Bubble Sort</button>

        </div>
       
    );
}




}
export default SortingVisualizer

function randomIntFromIntervals(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

EDIT: I beleive I may have solved it. I am going to try have a random array filled with unique vals no dups

Comment: Include the interesting parts of your code in your question. We should not have to leave StackOverflow to get a basic sense of the code in question.

Comment: @Marc added new code

Comment: You should use a unique key per element otherwise react can't patch the Dom. Right now you are using the array index. The position of the elements will change as you sort but without stable keys react can't detect changes very well and you will see these weird things. Id recommend that you add an id field on each element.

Comment: @Brenden yep that was my issue. I ended up just making the array create unqiue elements instead of duplicates to solve it but that would be a (probably better) way to go about it.